# ByteBuddy loaded class is slower than expected

Tags: java, kotlin, jvm, bytecode, byte-buddy

I'm using ByteBuddy to implement `hasComponent(KClass): Boolean` and `<T> findComponentOrNull(KClass): T?` for child classes of an `Entity` interface.

I've got it working, but it's around half the speed compared to a manual implementation.
Here's some simple benchmark results (codegen benchmark doesn't include the time it takes to generate the bytecode)

```
Benchmark                                                     Mode  Cnt          Score        Error  Units
CodegenBranchEntityBenchmark.findComponentOrNullBenchmark    thrpt    5   93353925.859 ± 626597.466  ops/s
ManualBranchEntityBenchmark.findComponentOrNullBenchmark     thrpt    5  213006529.660 ± 638025.482  ops/s
MapLookupEntityBenchmark.findComponentOrNullBenchmark        thrpt    5  168355957.091 ± 633810.959  ops/s
```

I've compared the bytecode of the generated implementation and the manual implementation and they're *almost* identical. I'm guessing the generated class isn't being processed by the JIT at all for some reason?

[`javap -c` output of manual implementation](https://gist.github.com/wine/48bc96641a19243d62e3f7c13821a8b9)

[`javap -c` output of generated implementation](https://gist.github.com/wine/29c14a67692bf326d9f275d8b7a0042b)

The only significant difference from what I can tell is that the Kotlin compiler creates a `PropertyReference1Impl` which shouldn't affect performance this much?

EDIT:
I changed `findComponentOrNull` to take in a regular Java `Class` (can skip invoking `JvmClassMappingKt#getJavaClass`) and it's now running at the same speed. Seems like the JIT doesn't optimize `KClass` on dynamically loaded types? I have no clue why, but works as expected now.

Comment: How are you measuring this?  It'd be perfectly normal for classes loaded later to be eligible for JIT later.

Comment: Hey @LouisWasserman I'm using KotlinX benchmark (JMH under the hood if unfamiliar), you can find the benchmarks [here](https://github.com/seppukudevelopment/seppuku2/tree/ecs-optimize/seppuku-sdk/ecs-codegen/src/test/kotlin/pw/seppuku/ecs/codegen)

Comment: I do not think that there is any particular reason. Are you running the latest JVM?

Comment: Questions about benchmark results without showing the benchmark are pointless. Besides that, both variants look convoluted to me. `Class` instances can be compared by reference (i.e. you can compare and branch with a single [`if_acmp` instruction](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se17/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.if_acmp_cond), instead of calling another method like `Intrinsics.areEqual(…)`, followed by `ifeq`). Also, there is no point in casting a reference to `java.lang.Object`. So you can shorten the entire method to 15 bytes. Though this might not have an effect on the performance…

Comment: @Holger using `if_acmpne` had close to no performance impact, I think it was how `JvmClassMappingKt#getJavaClass` works (maybe?) since I don't use it and am getting similar speeds to expected now

Comment: Well, I already said that I don’t expect an effect on performance (loading and verification time is outside the benchmark and still tiny for a single method). The two javap outputs you’ve posted both contain a `JvmClassMappingKt.getJavaClass` call, so that’s not explaining a difference in the outcome.

Comment: Hey @Holger [here](https://gist.github.com/wine/66a14672330f28ce55a54951a1fce7bf) is the javap output of the current generated code

Comment: Well, yes, the new code not containing a `JvmClassMappingKt.getJavaClass` call is faster than the previous version containing it. But that doesn’t explain why the manual implementation also containing the `JvmClassMappingKt.getJavaClass` call is faster.